# Need steps for clickhouse distributed query implementation

Tags: clickhouse

I have installed clickhouse in 2 different machines A(96GB RAM , 32 core) & B (96GB RAM , 32 core) and i also configured replica using zookeeper.
I am able to ingest and fetch the data from both the machines and replication also working fine.

Now i would like to utilize 2 clickhouse servers for single query to improve the query performance.

I tried for distributed query but i am failed to configure hence could please provide the clear steps to implement distributed query

Answer (score 2):

If I right understood you, the distributed query is executed just on one server utilizing both its replicas.

To fix it need to change the strategy of replicas selection by the load balancer to **in_order** (it defined in *user.xml* (to change any configs use [config overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834548/303298))):

```xml
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <!-- .. -->
            <load_balancing>in_order</load_balancing>
        </default>
    </profiles>
    <!-- .. -->
</yandex>
```

Refs:

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#load-balancing
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/

Comment: I changed the load balance but still query utilizing single server resource

Comment: SELECT
    name,
    value
FROM system.settings
WHERE name IN ('max_parallel_replicas', 'distributed_product_mode', 'load_balancing')

┌─name─────────────────────┬─value────┐
│ load_balancing           │ in_order │
│ max_parallel_replicas    │ 2        │
│ distributed_product_mode │ allow    │
└──────────────────────────┴──────────┘

Comment: SELECT *
FROM clusters

┌─cluster─┬─shard_num─┬─shard_weight─┬─replica_num─┬─host_name────┬─host_address─┬─port─┬─is_local─┬─user────┬─default_database─┐
│ logs    │         1 │            1 │           1 │ xx.xx.xx.142 │ xx.xx.xx.142 │ 9000 │        1 │ default │                  │
│ logs    │         1 │            1 │           2 │ xx.xx.xx.143 │ xx.xx.xx.143 │ 9000 │        1 │ default │                  │
└─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘

Comment: It looks like your cluster has just ONE shard and two replicas. The same query won't be parallelized between replicas, only between shards. You need to reconfigure cluster to have more than 1 shard.
Please look at these articles: 
https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2161
https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse