# Force reload the clickhouse config?

Tags: config, clickhouse

How can I forcefully reload the clickhouse configuration? I need to make changes to /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml (remote_servers). Can I force clickhouse to re-read the file without restarting the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make clickhouse take new users.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062749/how-to-make-clickhouse-take-new-users-xml-file)

Answer (score 6):

The server tracks changes to config files and files that were used for substitutions and overrides and reloads users and clusters configurations in runtime. That is, you can add or change users, clusters and their settings without relaunching the server. For remote_servers server read config immediately after the request

Answer (score 0):

Restart the ClickHouse Database to apply the configuration changes: in Ubuntu:

```
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```